# How to use std::max or std::min as function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, std-function

I like to pass `std::max` or `std::min` into a function. One can write code like this

Definition of the function

```
void foo (std::function<double(double, double)> extreme) {
    ...
    const double e = extreme(rhs, lhs);
    ...
}
```

On can call the function using a lambda

```
foo([](const double rhs, const double lhs) { return std::max(rhs, lhs); });
```

This is quite ugly. I would prefer to write code like this

```
foo(std::max);
```

This does not [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/xo5zs5). Is this or something more readable possible?

Comment: AFAIK, the lambda is the way to go.  To save yourself some typing, you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811716/most-terse-and-reusable-way-of-wrapping-template-or-overloaded-functions-in-func/65811783#65811783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
void foo (std::function<double const&(double const&, double const&)>) {}
void foo2 (double const&(double const&, double const&)){}

int main () {
    foo((double const&(*)(double const&, double const&))(std::max<double>));
    foo2(std::max<double>);
}
```

Note that we always need to use `std::max<double>`.

In the call to `foo`, as it takes a `std::function`, theres no good way the compiler can work out which overloaded version of `std::max` to use and so you need to cast it to the correct type.

For the second one, as `foo2` takes the raw function, it just works.

Note that I've explicitly use `double const&`, as the plain `T` versions (as in not having the `const&`) of `std::max` take an initialiser list and so there's no way to cast it to what you need.

So to get it working with the `foo` as written, you'll have to use a lambda or overload or wrapper of some sort.

So the simplest way would be to use the knowledge above of what does work, and add an overload:

```
void foo(double const&(*func)(double const&, double const&) )
{
    foo([&func](double a, double b){return func(a, b);});
}
```

and then `foo(std::max<double>);` will work

Comment: These functions are not [addressable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressable_functions), and hence this is UB.