# Is there an alternative to std::bind that doesn't require placeholders if function declarations match?

Tags: c++, c++17, std, stdbind

I have the following scenario quite often in my c++17 code.

Generic example:

```
class Receiver{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(const std::vector<uint8_t>& payload)> PROCESS_PACKET;
    PROCESS_PACKET m_callback;
    void run(){
        while(){
            // do stuff, then call callback:
            m_callback(data);
        }
    }
};

class UsesReceiver{
public:
    UsesReceiver(){
        receiver.m_callback=std::bind(&UsesReceiver::processData, this, std::placeholders::_1);
        receiver.run();
    }
private:
    void processData(const std::vector<uint8_t>& payload){
        // here do something implementation specific
    }
    Receiver receiver;
};
```

What always bugs me is this part:

```
receiver.m_callback=std::bind(&UsesReceiver::processData, this, std::placeholders::_1);
```

For this example it is quite simple, since the function only takes one parameter, but as soon as you have more parameters this part is a lot of boilerplate in my opinion.

Because I am thinking:
If there is a member function whoese definition is exactly the same as the declared function pointer (e.g. arguments and function type match) there should be a simple one-liner that checks these preconditions at compile time and looks basically like this:

```
receiver.m_callback=std::bind_quick(&UsesReceiver::processData,this);
```

Where std::bind_quick, is "just like std::bind" but without placeholders if both function declarations match (checked at compile time).

Since the first couple of comments were "use lambdas instead":
This doesn't really solve the problem, because with lambdas you still have to declare "placeholders" for your function arguments:

```
receiver.m_callback=[this](auto && PH1) { 
            processData(std::forward<decltype(PH1)>(PH1)); 
        };
```

Comment: Don't use `bind`, use a lambda instead.  Then you can use a technique like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811783/4342498

Comment: Of course, there is. Just use lambdas instead.

Comment: Without declaring an extra macro (which is something I'd like to avoid) using a lambda creates just as much boilerplate for functions with "a lot of arguments":
receiver.m_callback=[this](auto && PH1) { processData(std::forward<decltype(PH1)>(PH1)); };

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a macro?  Removing/Reducing boiler plate is one of the actual use cases for macros.  Why not use the tool that does the job?

Comment: You also don't need to be explicit about the placeholders when manually writing a lambda.  You can use `[this](auto...&& args) { processData(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); }`

Comment: Because I'd expect there to be a std implementation for that.

Comment: There is a std implementation for that in C++20: `std::bind_front`.

Comment: @ConstantinGeier c++ is not flooded with small utilities for convenience. There's a lot of different "default behaviours" one could want from an automatic member-function wrapper and writing one yourself is just a few lines of code.

Comment: @NathanOliver, it turns out my question is useful. Still nobody but one upvoted me :(

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments you should generally prefer lambdas over `std::bind`, even if it doesn't solve your issue.

It's fairly easy to create your `quick_bind` function using lambdas though.

```
template <typename Func, typename Obj>
auto quick_bind(Func f, Obj* obj) {
    return [=](auto&&... args) {
        return (obj->*f)(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Then use it like so

```
receiver.m_callback=quick_bind(&UsesReceiver::processData, this);
```

It returns a lambda with a templated operator, so if your assigning it to a `std::function` it will work as long as there's not a mismatch in function signature.

Answer (score 2):

I am of the position that you should have stopped using `std::bind` in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

Lambdas solve 99.9% of `std::bind` problems cleaner and in a way more likely to be understood, and you shouldn't even write the remaining 0.1% of `std::bind` code (which involves passing `std::bind`s to `std::bind` and the madness that results).

In the raw we get:

```
receiver.m_callback=[this](auto&payload){processData(payload);};
```

this is already simpler and clearer in my opinion.  Just language primitives, no library functions involved.

If you want a helper function

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), use `std::bind_front` or in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
template<class F, class...Args>
auto bind_front( F&& f, Args&&...args ) {
  return [f = std::forward<F>(f), tup=std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)](auto&&... more_args)
         ->decltype(auto)
  {
    return std::apply([&](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
      return std::invoke( f, decltype(args)(args)..., decltype(more_args)(more_args)... );
    }, tup);
  };
}
```

a bit of a mess, but gives you

```
receiver.m_callback=notstd::bind_front(&UsesReceiver::processData, this);
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/sT7Er3).

Answer (score 0):

Since I also got a really good solution in one of the comments, I am going to sum it up here:

If you are lucky enough to work with c++20, you can use `std::bind_front` as suggested by @StoryTeller.
For the example above, that would look like this:

```
receiver.m_callback=std::bind_front(&UsesReceiver::processData, this);
```

If you do not have c++20 support, you can also use [absl::bind_front](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/functional/bind_front.h#L19).
Excerpt:

> The simpler syntax of `absl::bind_front()` allows you to avoid known
> misuses with `std::bind()`

Else,you can also write your own macro or function, as suggested in the answer above or in the comment by @NathanOliver.