# Compilation error caused by macro in Microsoft Compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, macros, c++17

MSVC doesn't seem to appreciate the macro-based solution I was given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811783/5825294) to wrap a function template in a function object.

The macro is

```cpp
#define FUNCTORIZE(func) [](auto&&... val) \
noexcept(noexcept(func(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val)...))) -> decltype(auto) \
{return func(std::forward<decltype(val)>(val)...);}
```

to be used (for instance) like this

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
inline constexpr auto get = FUNCTORIZE(std::get<N>);
```

so that one obtains a function object that can be passed around like this

```cpp
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), get<1>);
```

And all works well in [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/rq9q5Wc7x) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/7eWffM7G9), but [MSVC errors like this](https://godbolt.org/z/1MT3zsG3d):

```
<source>(12): error C2760: syntax error: unexpected token 'identifier', expected ')'
<source>(18): note: see reference to variable template 'const auto get<1>' being compiled
Compiler returned: 2
```

- Probably I'd just need to add some compiler flag (other than one specifying a newer standard than C++17)?
- Would writing the macro differently help?
- Can I get that macro working in C++17 with MSVC?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? What is the language standard set to? Consider putting together a [mcve] that others could copy/paste/compile.

Comment: @RetiredNinja clicking on the last link will allow you to copy, paste, compile. Or just compile.

Comment: Compiles correctly for me with Visual Studio 2019 16.10.3 with C++ standard set to /std:c++latest. Also asserts on the `std::transform` line with "cannot seek value-initialized vector iterator" https://godbolt.org/z/z59jbPEz7

Comment: @TedLyngmo, corrected. It was an error I did when de-Rangev3-ifying the code. They work now on GCC and Clang.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I need C++17.

Comment: You asked if you needed a compiler flag. I gave one. After the edit it runs correctly as well.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, sorry, I was imprecise. I've clarified in the question now. Anyway good to know that the problem is solved with /std:c++latest.

Comment: cppinsights says "_INSIGHTS: Unexpected noexcept expr_" 3 times. Perhaps there's something there?

Comment: Why not just use `std::get` directly in `std::transform`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, because you can't. `std::get<N>` is still a templated function (templated on it's argument too), not a function object, so you can't pass its name around hoping that the argument deduction can be delayed. That's the whole point of the question I linked.

Comment: If `noexcept` part is removed, MSVC accepts the code with `/std:c++17`

Comment: That's very interesting, @IgorTandetnik, thanks!