# How do I use BOOST_HOF_LIFT and BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS with MSVC?

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, function-templates, function-object

(This is in part a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811716/most-terse-and-reusable-way-of-wrapping-template-or-overloaded-functions-in-func/68357266#68357266) question of mine.)

As I've written in [this self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68357266/5825294), I've discovered that Boost offers a [macro to *wrap a template function in a function object so it can be passed to higher-order functions*](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html):

```cpp
#include <boost/hof.hpp>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

// Declare the class `max_f`
BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS(max_f, std::max);

int main() {
    auto my_max = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::max);
    assert(my_max(3, 4) == std::max(3, 4));
    assert(max_f()(3, 4) == std::max(3, 4));
}
```

The point is that things don't quite work well with MSVC, and the problem hits me especially when some of the template parameters cannot be deduced and corresponding arguments must be provided explicitly, as is the case for `std::get`, just to make an example.

The following works with GCC, but errors with MSVC

```cpp
template<int N>
auto constexpr getNth_a = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::get<N>);
// usage
std::tuple<int,int> t{1,2};
getNth_a<0>(t); // errors with MSVC
```

So I tried `BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS` instead, but I can't get it working when templated, not even in GCC:

```cpp
template<int N>
BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS(getNth_b, std::get<N>);
// attempted usage
std::tuple<int,int> t{1,2};
getNth_b<0>(t); // doens't even work with GCC
```

[Here's a demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/jn883hGhj)

Comment: Your `getNth_b` problem is of a different nature. You use it wrong (and the example should have been here, not behind a link). `getNth_b<0>` is a type, so `getNth_b<0>(t);` is a variable (re-)declaration (most vexing parse). To create a functor instance and immediately call it we'd do `getNth_b<0> {} (t);`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I've included the example usage in the question.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, I have no idea why I deleted this. However, feel free to post the comment as answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: For some reason, I see my question copied [here](https://windowsquestions.com/2021/07/13/how-do-i-use-boost_hof_lift-and-boost_hof_lift_class-with-msvc/).