# Does Boost (or another library) offer a way to lift the name of a "constructor-less" class into a function object that uses aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, boost, functional-programming, c++17, function-object

This is kind of a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65811716/5825294), where I asked how I could tersely turn a template and/or overloaded function into a function object.

The accepted answer was *you can't do without macro*, which is correct. Then I found that such a macro is offered by Boost, in the form of the [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT` and `BOOST_HOF_LIFT_CLASS` macros](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html).

It turns out, however, that there are other "named things" you can't pass around. I don't know all of them, but one of them is *constructors*. And Boost.Hof offers a way to lift them to, via [`boost::hof::construct`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/construct.html).

The point is that not even `boost::hof::construct` can deal with a class without a user-declared constructor. For intance, given

```
struct Foo {
    int foo;
};
```

the call `boost::hof::construct<Foo>()(3)` simply doesn't work. (Adding the constructor `Foo(int) {}` in `Foo` makes it work; that's what `boost::hof::construct` is for, after all.)

Surely, in simple cases like the one above I could just write

```
auto makeFoo = [](int x){ return Foo{x}; };
```

but if I want to support any type, I have to take care of perfect forwarding and variadic arguments.

Is there a library offering this feature already? [It doesn't look like Boost.Hof does...](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/hof/doc/html/doc/src/reference.html)

Comment: At this point, there's not much reason to provide such functionality. C++20 allows aggregate initialization through constructor `()` syntax, so such a thing would only be useful for pre-C++20 projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a function object that constructs an object of some type `T` given some parameters, even if `T` is an aggregate, that's not difficult to write in C++17:

```
template<typename T>
struct lifted_construct
{
  template<typename ...Args>
  T operator() (Args&& ...args)
  {
    if constexpr(std::is_aggregate_v<T>)
    {
      return T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
    }
    else
    {
      return T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  }
};
```

Of course, in C++20, you can use `()` syntax even for aggregates.

Comment: I guess `boost::hof::construct` doesn't use such a technique because Boost.Hof is meant to be a C++11/C++14 library, and [`std::is_aggregate_v`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_aggregate) is from C++17 (and, if I understand correctly, it can't be implemented in the language and therefore needs compiler support).