# How to declare the template argument for an overloaded function

Tags: c++, function, templates, overload-resolution, template-argument-deduction

I have a fairly big project that, regarding this question,
I can summarize with
[this structure:](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EMaq3hKP4)

```
void do_something()
{
    //...
}

template<typename F> void use_funct(F funct)
{
    // ...
    funct();
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    use_funct(do_something);
}
```

All is working ok until someone (me) decides to reformat a little
minimizing some functions, rewriting
[as this minimum reproducible example:](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dMEEc9eq4)

```
void do_something(const int a, const int b)
{
    //...
}

void do_something()
{
    //...
    do_something(1,2);
}

template<typename F> void use_funct(F funct)
{
    // ...
    funct();
}

int main()
{
    // ...
    use_funct(do_something);
}
```

And now the code doesn't compile with
*error: no matching function for call*
where `use_funct` is instantiated.

Since the error message was not so clear to me
and the changes were a lot I wasted a considerable
amount of time to understand that the compiler
couldn't deduce the template parameter
because `do_something` could now refer to
any of the overloaded functions.

I removed the ambiguity changing the function name,
but I wonder if there's the possibility to avoid
this error in the future not relying on template
argument deduction.
How could I specify in this case the template argument for `do_something()`, possibly without referring to a function pointer?
I haven't the slightest idea to express explicitly:

`use_funct<`*-the-one-with-no-arguments-*`>(do_something);`

Comment: Wrap the function call in a lambda.  related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811716/most-terse-and-reusable-way-of-wrapping-template-or-overloaded-functions-in-func

Comment: maybe `use_funct<void()>(do_something)`?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Why I'm feeling a little stupid?

Comment: @NathanOliver I was missing that, reading now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the function in a lambda, or pass a function pointer after casting it to the type of the overload you want to call or explicitly specify the template parameter:

```
use_funct([](){ do_something (); });
use_funct(static_cast<void(*)()>(do_something));
use_funct<void()>(do_something);
```

Wrapping it in a lambda has the advantage, that it is possible to defer overload resolution to `use_func`. For example:

```
void do_something(int) {}

void do_something(double) {}

template<typename F> void use_funct(F funct) {   
    funct(1);    // calls do_something(int)
    funct(1.0);  // calls do_something(double)
}

int main() {   
    use_funct([](auto x){ do_something (x); });
}
```

> [...] possibly without referring to a function pointer?

I am not sure what you mean or why you want to avoid that. `void()` is  the type of the function, not a function pointer. If you care about spelling out the type, you can use an alias:

```
using func_type = void();
use_funct<func_type>(do_something);
```