# How can I specify an overload when passing an overloaded function to another?

Tags: c++, overloading, c++20, overload-resolution

Simple example:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings{"1","2","3");
std::vector<double> doubles(3);
transform(begin(strings), end(strings), begin(doubles), std::stod);
```

This fails to compile because the compiler cannot decide which `std::stod` to use. The one that takes an `std::string` or the one that takes an `std::wstring`. We see that only one would work given how `std::transform` works, but the compiler doesn't.

**Options (bad ones)**

- Now, we *cannot* say `std::stod<std::string>` because `std::stod` is not a template but an overload. And even if it was a template, it would have to be a class template with a static non-templated function: `Stod<std::string>::stod`.
- What I usually do is use a lambda: `[](std::string const& s) { return std::stod(s); }` but that is quite a lot of code for nothing.
- There is also the option to cast the overloaded function to the specific type (`double (*)(std::string const&)`) but to do that, I have to know the return type. For `std::stod` that is simple, because it always returns a simple `double` but for other functions that might be a very complicated thing to write down.

Is there a more concise way than the lambda to select the correct overload or trick the compiler into figuring it out itself?

Answer (score 2):

As you already know, you either resolve the overload upfront by casting, i.e. choosing one of the overloads, or you delay the overload resolution by wrapping the call in a function object (being it a lambda or something else).

The quickest way to take the latter approach, without writing any code of yours, is Boost.Hof's [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html).

So instead of passing this

```cpp
std::stod
```

you pass this

```cpp
BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::stod)
```

Isn't it concise enough?

([Working example on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/495rf8qPY).)

Comment: Looks like an option, but using macros always does makes me a bit uncomfortable.

Comment: If used more than one time, then `BOOST_HOF_LIFT` _does_ become more concise than writing the lambdas manually.

Comment: @bitmask, macros is the only non-verbose tool that you have at your disposal in this case. If you want a non-macro solution to pass an overloaded and/or templated entity to a function call, I'm afraid you need to make a proposal for the standard.

Comment: @Enlico I don't disagree.

Answer (score 1):

- You would need to help the compiler to select overload:

  ```
  static_cast<double(*)(const std::string&, std::size_t*)>(std::stod)
  ```
- This does not work anyway. `std::stod` requires 2 arguments. The default value for the argument doesn't tag along with the function pointer you give to `transform` to work with.
- You also take the address of a function in the standard library which isn't allowed (with [a few exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Designated_addressable_functions) - but `std::stod` is not one of them).

The simplest solution for all is to package it in a lambda:

```
std::transform(std::begin(strings), std::end(strings), std::begin(doubles),
               [](const std::string& s) { return std::stod(s); });
```

> Is there a more concise way than the lambda to select the correct overload or trick the compiler into figuring it out itself?

No, none that is portable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I stated that I am aware both ideas in the OP and specifically asked for a more concise option.

Comment: @bitmask Sorry, I left answering the actual question out. Added that now.

Comment: @bitmask I hate saying it, but use a macro to wrap that lambda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65811783/4342498

Comment: @NathanOliver Now, *that* actually *is* a duplicate. Closed this question as such.