# Can function templates be used as first class citizens in higher order function calls?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, higher-order-functions, first-class-functions

Passing a function template as argument to another function template is always a bit tricky. Typically one has to resort to creating a lambda object that goes and calls the original function.

### Example

```
template <typename It>
void f(It, It) {}

void g(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator) {}

template <typename C, typename F>
void callA(C&& c, F callable) {
  return callable(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

### Problem

If I have a `std::vector<int> c`, I cannot just pass `f` along to `callA` because `f` is a template and not a function:

```
callA(c, f); // f has an unresolved overloaded function type and cannot be deduced
callA(c, std::distance); // same problem
callA(c, g); // works because g is a proper function, not a template
callA(c, [](auto a, auto b) {return f(a,b);}); // works again
```

Even if we help deduce the type of the callable:

```
template <typename C, template <typename> typename F,
          typename T = std::decay_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<C>()))>>
auto callB(C&& c, F<T> callable) {
  return callable(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

this [fails to compile](https://godbolt.org/z/xjax7d1ba).

### Question

Is there a way to force C++ to deduce the function's type directly without resorting to a lambda function or type-erasure like `std::function`? Effectively, (how) **can I turn a function template into a first-class citizen**? That is, have its type deduced.

I'm willing to go to some lengths when *defining* the higher-order function (see `callB` versus `callA`), but not when *calling* it.

Comment: Re: (how) can I turn a function template into a first-class citizen?, by lambdas, as you've correctly guessed. Function overloads and template specializations might differ from point to point (due to different includes), hence the need to explicitly say, I'm capturing it here.

Comment: @lorro Yeah, but the point is that forcing me to wrap a function call in a lambda means the function is *not* a "first-class citizen". It is second class.

Comment: Can you use function pointer as parameter? Which could be converted from function templates.

Comment: @songyuanyao Sure, but how do you get the correct function pointer?

Comment: @bitmask What I'm saying, it's not a citizen at all. Consider that, in a.cpp you see the template specialization and in b.cpp you don't see it. What should the capture be? It's different from location to location.

Comment: @lorro I see what you mean. But the call is explicitly in a particular line in a particular file. So **that's** where you "capture" it.

Comment: Your second attempt is incorrect simply because there is no class template (or alias template) that matches `F`. A function has a type, but a function *template* doesn't have a type template.

Comment: Use std::bind! I'm just joking, but frankly, since C++20 your problem probably is no problem anymore (--and you seem to know that). Just replace `template <typename It>
void f(It, It) {}` beforehand against `auto f = []<typename It>(It, It) {}`. And if you have no access to `f`, do the lambda-wrapping once inside `callA`.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the parameter type to function pointer, which could be converted from function template (with template argument deduced). E.g.

```
template <typename C>
void callA(C&& c, void(*callable) (std::decay_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<C>()))>, std::decay_t<decltype(std::begin(std::declval<C>()))>)) {
  return callable(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}
```

Then

```
std::vector<int> c;
callA(c, f); // template argument It will be deduced as std::vector<int>::iterator for f
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/18oU4pFabZTQnN1v)

Comment: It will not work with non-function callables such as capturing lambdas or `std::function`, but this can be fixed by simply adding the original OP's `callA` as an overload.

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, only that one has to fix the callable's return type. So, a function like `f` which returns void would require a different `callA` than, say, `std::distance`.

Comment: @bitmask This is not necessary, you can add another template parameter for the return type

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I can't get the inference to work. I can get it to work such that you can say `callA<std::ptrdiff_t>(a, std::distance)` and `callA(a, f)` (by defaulting to `void`). But I don't see a way to get `callA(a, std::distance)` to work automatically.

Comment: @bitmask hmm that's right, inference doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware of [`BOOST_HOF_LIFT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/hof/doc/html/include/boost/hof/lift.html)?

It allows you to lift overloaded and/or templated functions into objects with as easy syntax as `auto my_max = BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::max);`.

You could change `callA(c, std::distance)` to `callA(c, BOOST_HOF_LIFT(std::distance))`.

Comment: lift is a macro that defines a lambda around the template

Comment: @Caleth, [I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65811716/most-terse-and-reusable-way-of-wrapping-template-or-overloaded-functions-in-func), but not having to write yourself the lambda is a great thing, imho. I mean a range-`for` loop is desugared into a "normal" `for` loop, but isn't it a useful abstraction?